# PHP Error When Trying to View PHPMyAdmin with WAMP

Tags: php, wamp

this question has been asked a couple of times here. However, I followed the directions and still cannot find the solution.

I installed WAMP yesterday (on Windows 7) and everything was working fine. After starting it up today I receive the following error when trying to view `PHPMyAdmin`.

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function mb_detect_encoding() in C:\wamp\apps\phpmyadmin4.0.4\libraries\php-gettext\gettext.inc on line 177
```

From what I read I needed to make sure that the `gd` and `mbstring` extension is enabled. From what I see in my `PHP.ini` file below it looks like it is.

```
;extension=php_bz2.dll
;extension=php_curl.dll
;extension=php_dba.dll
;extension=php_exif.dll
;extension=php_fileinfo.dll
extension=php_gd2.dll
;extension=php_gettext.dll
;extension=php_gmp.dll
;extension=php_intl.dll
;extension=php_imap.dll
;extension=php_interbase.dll
;extension=php_ldap.dll
extension=php_mbstring.dll
;extension=php_ming.dll
;extension=php_mssql.dll
extension=php_mysql.dll
extension=php_mysqli.dll
;extension=php_oci8.dll      
;extension=php_oci8_11g.dll 
;extension=php_openssl.dll
;extension=php_pdo_firebird.dll
;extension=php_pdo_mssql.dll
extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll
;extension=php_pdo_oci.dll
;extension=php_pdo_odbc.dll
;extension=php_pdo_pgsql.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlite.dll
;extension=php_pgsql.dll
;extension=php_phar.dll
;extension=php_pspell.dll
;extension=php_shmop.dll
;extension=php_snmp.dll
;extension=php_soap.dll
;extension=php_sockets.dll
;extension=php_sqlite.dll
;extension=php_sqlite3.dll
;extension=php_sybase_ct.dll
;extension=php_tidy.dll
;extension=php_xmlrpc.dll
;extension=php_xsl.dll
;extension=php_zip.dll
```

Any ideas?

Comment: The error is indeed complaining about the lack of the mbstring extension. Since you show it uncommented, the only thing that comes to mind is that you may need to restart your web server for the next extension to be made available to php.

Comment: Thank you! That is what I was thinking too. I restarted the server several times with no luck. Should I reboot or is restarting the server good enough? I am going to post the full php.ini file in the next couple of minutes. Thanks

Comment: Here it is http://snipt.org/APgi5

Comment: The only other thing that even makes sense aside from a server restart is that the `extension_dir` path is wrong, or you don't have the mbstring extension. Since you posted the php.ini, all I can say is check to make sure you have a file at `c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.4.12/ext/php_mbstring.dll`. If you do, that's exactly where it should be and I'm out of ideas. This is the sort of thing that I need to be on the machine to try to debug.

Comment: Give XAMPP a try. I have tried wamp several times, but in the end I always go back to xampp for some reason. There are several issues with it.

Comment: Can you check this menu on WAMP? `PHP -> PHP extensions -> mb_string`?

Comment: Thanks @Nate. It is located where you said it should be.

Comment: @MahanGM It is checked..

Comment: I restarted the computer and that did not work either. It is so strange that it worked fine when I installed it yesterday and now it doesn't. I didn't even change anything. Seems like I had problems like that with WAMP on another computer back in the day.

Comment: There are two `php.ini` in your PHP folder. One is for CLI and the other for Apache. Make sure you enable the extension for both files just to be sure. (That is in case you haven't tried that). The path to the `php.ini` file is `C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.10`. There should be only two `.ini` files in that folder. On my version of Wamp I have: `php.ini` and `phpForApache.ini`. I don't remember if i renamed the one for Apache, but you shouldn't have any problem locating them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

nt.bas is right up to the place where (s)he says you should edit the phpForApache.ini file **DO NOT**.

Use the Wampmanage menus to edit the Apache version of the php.ini file. 
left click wampmanager -> PHP -> php.ini
This will edit the c:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.x.y\bin\php.ini ( the correct file )

To activate/deactivate PHP extensions, there are also menus to do this.
Left click wampmanager -> PHP -> Extensions -> ( you will see a list of extensions ). If the extension is ticked it is active. To activate an extension simply click the one you want to activate, wait 3-4 seconds while apache is Automatically restarted to activate the extension. Then if you need to activate another do the same again, dont rush it, remember Apache is being restarted after each click to activate or deactivate an extension.

If you are getting this error, the most likely reason is that yo have edited, or are looking at the wrong php.ini file.
C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.x.y\php.ini is used when you are running PHP as a CLI ( Command Line Interface )

Use the menus provided to avoid making this mistake.

PS
The phpForApache.ini is the file WAMP Server uses to save the Apache version of the php.ini file when you switch from one version of PHP to another, so you should not edit it directly unless you really know what you are doing with WAMP.

Answer (score 3):

well I don´t know if you resolved this issue. I had the same problem and I tried anything posted here and other forums, and nothing happened. After all, just for a curious way, I tried it: Press the wamp icon(in green), go to MySql--> Service --> and Press Install Service. VOILA! Now PhpMyAdmin is working. I hope it help you!

George

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, and if none of the above posts work, as they did not for me follow the following steps-

1. If you can access this url- localhost/?phpinfo=1 or just go to localhost and click on phpinfo(). If an error is coming on phpmyadmin, that means your apache, php and mysql are running fine, hence this should not be an issue.
2. Check the "Loaded Configuration File" Url. In my case it was "C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.2.22\bin\php.ini". Mostly the php.ini inside apache is the one that is utilized for all tasks.
3. Open that file in notepad, Check the "extension_dir". It should be pointing to the correct path. If you are using php 5.3.13, please check it is pointing to c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.3.13/ext/, and not any other path.

Once done, save it and restart your server. You should be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

Try oracle Mysql Workbrench. and try to reinstall your phpmyadmin. My experience say me: Reinstall your php myadmin and it's should be work. it's not related to your server. because one day I faced with this problem. I used mysql workbrench week and automatically phpmyadmin worked after 3 weeks!.

Answer (score 0):

There are two configuration files for wamp (actually three if you take into account the one in the Apache bin folder). Anyways, Wamp uses two configuration files:

- One is for CLI (command prompt) and that is `php.ini`,
- The other is for Apache and that `phpForApache.ini`.

phpMyAdmin runs in the browser and therefore needs Apache in order to interface with PHP. So any changes you make to the configuration file needs to happen in `phpForApache.ini` in order to be reflected in a PHP application running in the browser.

Wamp will give you `php.ini` when you request the configuration file using: `Wamp -> PHP -> php.ini` but that's the wrong configuration file for normal PHP developers. You need to go to `C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.x.xx`, look for `phpForApache.ini`, makes changes there, restart Wamp and everything should be in the green, so to speak.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I downloaded `XAMPP` and started using that since I could not get it going. Quick question that I noticed with `XAMPP` and `WAMP`. In `PHPMyAdmin`, there is a table called `test`. When I installed `WAMP` I actually deleted that table thinking it was just that, a test table. However, after seeing it in both applications I am beginning to wonder if that was the problem? Do you happen to know if that could have caused the error?

Comment: @Chris78 Okay :-) No the `test database` (not `table`) is supplied with MySQL (so will show up in XAMPP and WAMP) and deleting it should not be problem - because it is probably used just for testing the MySQL installation. I should be empty as well (no tables in it). If it was not empty, then there is something more to your MySQL installation and I can't tell the effect of deleting it. If it was a table as you say, in which database was it? That could have an effect on `phpMyAdmin` since it comes with three databases itself.

Answer (score 0):

Simply check your broswer and make sure it not using any proxy or check use no proxy. That might help.

Answer (score -1):

Go to

```
C:/wamp/apps/phpmyadmin4.1.14/libraries/php-gettext/gettext.inc
```

open it with note pad and search for `mb_detect_encoding` because it's our function that not has declared then replace it with `_get_codeset` witch is been declared right above ;

I think when they changed versions they forget it.